# Getting Library contents along with Folder structure [Console application using Object Model]

Tags: 2007, document-library, object-model, console-application

I am developing a console application which will get all the files in a document library and copy it to a particular location on system. I was successful in retrieving all the files within the library. **However , i am unable to retain the folder structure. Files in diff folder are place in the library without the original structure i.e all in one place.** Below is the code:

```
if ((list.GetType().ToString()=="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary") && !list.Hidden)
                    {
                        var Listdir = Sitedir+@"\"+list.Title.ToString();

                        if (!Directory.Exists(Listdir))
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(Listdir); 
                        Console.WriteLine(list.Title);


                        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                        {

                            byte[] binFile = item.File.OpenBinary();

                            System.IO.FileStream fstream =

                            System.IO.File.Create(Listdir+"\\" + item.File.Name);

                            fstream.Write(binFile, 0, binFile.Length);

                            Console.WriteLine(item.File.Name);
                        }
                    }
```

**Is there any way to retain folder structure?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas,

[Traversing SharePoint List Folder Hierarchies](http://blog.krichie.com/2007/01/30/traversing-sharepoint-list-folder-hierarchies/)

From above URL:

```
// Within some method somewhere
foreach(SPList list in web.Lists)
{
    if(list.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
    {
        //Traverse the folder
        TraverseFolder(list.RootFolder);
    }
}

TraverseFolder might be implemented something like this:

public long TraverseFolder(SPFolder folder)
{
    // Do something interesting on the folder
    // Perhaps sum up the file sizes

    long lFolderSize = 0;
    try
    {
        foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files)
            lFolderSize += file.Length;

        if (bRecurseFolders)
        {
            foreach (SPFolder subfolder in folder.SubFolders)
                lFolderSize += TraverseFolder(subfolder);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    return lFolderSize;
}
```

I always use this for referencing, I hope this helps!

Comment: Superb.Thanks a lot for this.Approach in this is entirely different :). Using this, i got the desired result. The only problem is that its including hidden folders too i.e "Forms", "FormServerTemplates" etc.

Comment: @ThomasMathew for that there are alternatives as suggested here: [Checking Programatically, if Document Library Folder is Hidden](http://youdhbir.blogspot.com/2012/04/checking-programatically-if-document.html).. Please mark the answer as correct if that helped!

Comment: I had tried that. But it wont work. Also, checking property count as 21 would not work too. Anyway, i have marked the answer as correct.